# How do I simulate reading strings from stdin in Clojure test when my src code expects a text file?

Tags: clojure

I have a main function that expects a file as an argument. The application then reads the lines from this file, processes them, and prints a JSON to stdout for each output.

```
(defn -main
  [& args]
  (print-all (-> args first read-input! input-received)))
```

I'm currently testing it by providing a sample input file:

```
(testing "Create account"
    (is (= (str (cheshire/generate-string {:account {:active-card true :available-limit 100} :violations []}) \newline)
           (with-out-str
             (io/-main "test/sample-input.txt")))))
```

However, I'd like to provide the strings directly into the test. Something like this:

```
(testing "Create account"
    (is (= (str (cheshire/generate-string {:account {:active-card true :available-limit 100} :violations []}) \newline)
           (with-out-str
             (io/-main "{\"account\": {\"active-card\": true, \"available-limit\": 100}}")))))
```

But it doesn't work this way. How could I make the test work with strings instead of files?

---

*Edit:*

I seem to have solved it this way:

```
(testing "Create account"
    (is (= (str (cheshire/generate-string {:account {:active-card true :available-limit 100} :violations []}) \newline)
           (with-out-str
             (with-in-str "{\"account\": {\"active-card\": true, \"available-limit\": 100}}"
               (io/-main *in*)))))))
```

Would there be a more straightforward or elegant solution?

Comment: I tried to use `with-in-str`, but couldn't make the argument be passed to `io/-main`. I tried it like this: `(with-in-str "{\"account\": {\"active-card\": true, \"available-limit\": 100}}" (io/-main))`. But `io/-main` doesn't seem to see the string as an argument.

Comment: Args to main are just strings, so this is treated as a *file name*. If you want to test *that* feature I doubt there is a way around other than creating a file beforehand and run that test. If you want to use STDIN, then make your main more flexible and also allow for reading from STDIN (in case no argument was passed - the classic unix approach). Or even better do and test both. What you can "fake" also depends on how `read-input!` is implemented.